# draw a rectangle using rect method from android graphics but i want the rectangle to fit any screen

Tags: android

i want to draw a rectangle using rect method form android graphics but i want to specify the values in dp so that it can fix to any screen size. i presume by default its in pixel or just x,y coordinates.
how can i draw it to fit in any screen size using the rect method

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) to obtain the screen's size and pixel density and then calculate your rectangle's width and height accordingly by adjusting the width and height in relation to the screen's characteristics.

Comment: can you help me how to implement it on the following code:

mBounds = new Rect(0,0,320,48);